# Notepad++ illegal XML character target search using Regex

Tags: pdf, notepad++, regex, xml

Fellow Forum Members,

I am using the latest version of NotePad++ and I have done a search for illegal XML symbols such as  "&", ">", "<", "©" among 200 separate XML files. I found a couple of illegal XML characters using a standard search however this did not find all of them. In short, there are some straggling illegal XML characters hiding somewhere among the 200 XML text files and I need to find them or else I am doomed.

Is there anyway possible I could use NotePad++ so it automatically finds for me illegal XML Characters among 200 separate XML files? Will a RegEx do the trick? If I could get my NotePad++ to accomplish such a task it will help me find that needle in a haystack that is ruining the XML code for my PDF publication that derives from 200 separate XML files.

Any help will be tremendously appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] and clarify.  It reads like you are using N++ to find the characters, and this is not working, so you want to use N++ to find the characters.

Comment: Why not run the document through an XML parser? Most will tell you where they encounter an error (like an invalid character).

Comment: Thanks for your postings. I have tried the parser already and it doesn

Comment: and it is not able to target these illegal XML characters.  My hope was a RegEx could be written to find any possible illegal XML character using the latest version of NotePad++.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If you have the XML Tools plugin, you can use the Plugins\Xml Tools\Check Xml Syntax Now option to see where the xml goes wrong.